All fields are not visible on page in Sitecore Content Hub
I have created one content type in Content Hub, below are the fields:

Test Title (Single-line text)
Is Checked (Boolean)
Submitted On (Datetime)
Has Reviewed (Boolean)
Birthdate (Datetime)


Below is a Schema:


Then I created one page but on that page, I can see only the below fields, other fields are not visible.

Test Title


Can anyone help me to identify why other fields are not visible?

Are these fields visible on Page under Manage => Pages?

Please perform the following steps and verify:

In Content Hub, click on the Manage button on the top right corner and choose the Pages option.
In the left panel expand the Content option and click on the Content Detail page.
On the Content Details page, in the right Panel scroll down and click on The Entity Details component.

Now on Details Component page, in the left panel search your content type Content (TestDemo) and TestDemo details and enable it.
After enabling you can also set the Visible member properties of each field.

